# Automate maintainance of AD groups, telephone number etc using data from Salesforce objects

Tags: soql

Currently we are using Imanami to synchronize data in table /view from application on MS SQL server to maintain  AD groups, telephone number, address etc.  How do we achieve the same i.e. update AD groups, user information etc from SFDC object? Any suggestio? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For those of us who don't know, what do you mean by AD groups?

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe your environment so here's one integration suggestion for a scenario where Salesforce is acting as the identity provider.

The Salesforce solution to integration between a User Identity in Salesforce to Microsoft Active Directory where Salesforce is acting as the Identity Provider (IdP) is supported by a licensed product called [Identity Connect](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/identity_id_connect.htm).

It is a Java app that runs on a server within your enterprise infrastructure on either a Linux or Microsoft host.

Identity Connect implementation guide:

- http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/identity_connect_impl_guide.pdf